# How to set a custom ID when pushing a new object into Firebase

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Firebase with AngularJS in my application. When a user logs into the app with the Facebook authentication I want to create a new user object (with some properties coming from Facebook and some relative to my app) and store it in Firebase. It's simple, I'm pushing the new User object:

```
...
var travelBidsFirebaseRef = new Firebase(url);
var newUserRef = travelBidsFirebaseRef.child("user").push(user, callback);
...
```

`push()` generates a unique ID, smth. like: -J08SgyOeOU_fFb1CB3G. So the only way I can access this User object is by using this ID:

```
angularFire(travelBidsFirebaseRef + "/user/-J08SgyOeOU_fFb1CB3G", $scope, 'user', {});
```

But when I receive authentication data from Facebook I have only Facebook ID and there is no way of me knowing the Firebase ID generated earlier (otherwise I would have to maintain a map of all users, which I don't want to).
So here is the question: **how do I save new User to the Firebase with a custom ID, e.g. Facebook ID?**

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Instead of using `push()`, use `set()` with the Facebook ID:

```
travelBidsFirebaseRef.child("user").child(facebookId).set(user, callback);
```

If you are using simple login and multiple auth providers (e.g. Facebook and Twitter at the same time) <del>then be sure you split out your users by provider, as IDs can possibly clash</del>

<del>travelBidsFirebaseRef.child("user/facebook/"+facebookId).set(user, callback);</del>

**Update**

As of FirebaseSimpleLogin 1.0, you can now use `uid`, which is unique across providers:

```
new FirebaseSimpleLogin(ref, function(err, user) {
   if( err ) throw err;
   travelBidsFirebaseRef.child('user/'+user.uid).set(user, callback);
});
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also try something like this:

```js
var empsRef = ref.child("employees");

empsRef.child('11111').set({
  lastname: "Lee",
  firstname: "Kang"
});

empsRef.child('22222').set({
  lastname: "Nut",
  firstname: "Dough"
});
```

The output should look like this:

```js
"employees" : {
  "11111" : {
    "lastname" : "Lee",
    "firstname": "Kang"
  },
  "22222" : {
    "lastname" : "Nut",
    "firstname": "Dough"
  }
}
```

Comment: Finally I get it, so we can use listeners at any level. Now I have finally figured out how to properly use real time db. I was stuck thinking that only the top level objects can be listened for. But actually we can listen to branched. Nice!

Answer (score -1):

do something like this:

```
  employees.update({
    "1" : {
      "lastname" : "Doe",
      "firstname": "John"
    },
    "2" : {
      "lastname" : "Loca",
      "firstname": "Maria"
    }
  });
```

Comment: how is this answer any different from the one posted 2 years prior