# Setting users' own key in Firebase

Tags: firebase, angularfire, firebase-authentication, firebase-realtime-database

The question is asked already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24560075/setting-your-own-key-when-adding-an-object-to-firebase-angularfire), but since AngularFire updates their API, the provided solution is not usable anymore.

What I am doing is to create new user's account with email/password, store that user in Firebase Authentication service, and store extra information in the database.

However, in the Authentication, user has their key as `simplelogin:29`, and in the Data, each user has their hashed key, as `-JpwB9oUVkeT_XRdiX2V`. I do need their keys to be the same.

Below is the code to create new user, registered with auth.$createUser and store extra information in  the user model.

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

auth.$createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password 
    }).then(function(regUser) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/')
    var firebaseUser = $firebaseArray(ref);

    var userInfo = {
        key         : regUser.uid, // ex: simplelogin:29
        date        : Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        firstname   : user.firstname,
        lastname    : user.lastname,
        email       : user.email,
    }; // user info

    firebaseUser.$add(userInfo);
});
```

It works, but not the way supposed to be, as a user's key in Authentication and Data are still different.

Answer (score 2):

When you're storing user data, you typically want to key on `uid`. After all the `uid` is already unique and using is as the key ensures that you'll never end up with two nodes for the same `uid`.

When you call `$add` it generates a new so-called push ID for the object that you're storing. This is great when you have lists of data, but in this case your data structure is more map like: you map `uid` to the user info.

So the solution is to not call `$add`, but instead:

```
var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/');
var auth = $firebaseAuth(ref);

auth.$createUser({
    email: user.email,
    password: user.password 
}).then(function(regUser) {

    var ref = new Firebase('https://myapp.firebaseio.com/users/')

    var userInfo = {
        key         : regUser.uid, // ex: simplelogin:29
        date        : Firebase.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
        firstname   : user.firstname,
        lastname    : user.lastname,
        email       : user.email,
    }; // user info

    ref.child(regUser.uid).set(userInfo);
});
```

Note that this just uses the regular [Firebase JavaScript SDK](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/), which will interact totally fine with any AngularFire listeners you may already have on the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like this:

```js
var empsRef = ref.child("http://sample.com/employees");

empsRef.child('11111').set({
  lastname: "Lee",
  firstname: "Kang"
});

empsRef.child('22222').set({
  lastname: "Nut",
  firstname: "Dough"
});
```

The output should look like this:

```js
"employees" : {
  "11111" : {
    "lastname" : "Lee",
    "firstname": "Kang"
  },
  "22222" : {
    "lastname" : "Nut",
    "firstname": "Dough"
  }
}
```