# Setting more attributes to User than Email and Password.

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

I'm developing a web app with Firebase. When using the createUser() method of Firebase Angularjs API I can only define the Email and the Password of the User.

IS there any way to define other attributes like: First name, last name, age etc..

Comment: Can you `createUser` and then use `set` in the onComplete callback to add the other attributes? https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/firebase/set.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase does not automatically store any data you pass to `createUser()` in a place that you have access to with a public API.

If you want to have access to data about your users from your application, you'll need to store it in your database yourself. Typically this data is stored under a top-level `/users` node, with each user being stored in their `uid`. See the [section on storing user data in the Firebase documentation](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/user-auth.html#section-storing) for some examples of this.

You'll note that this reference is of the Firebase JavaScript SDK. AngularFire does not have any API built-in for storing user data. But since AngularFire is built on top of the Firebase JavaScript SDK, the two interoperate without problems, so you can pick whichever of the APIs that allows you to accomplish your task at hand.

*edit*: I just noticed that the [AngularFire seed application](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed) does something similar in its [account](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/master/app/account/account.js) and [login](https://github.com/firebase/angularfire-seed/blob/4787b6aba6a4a03605260c966766f33262d786bc/app/login/login.js#L40-L43) handling.

*edit2*: these seem relevant:

- [Add Extra Details on Firebase User Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31038611/add-extra-details-on-firebase-user-table/31039334#31039334)
- [Setting users' own key in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30400890/setting-users-own-key-in-firebase/30403314#30403314)
- [How do I return a list of users if I use the Firebase simple username & password authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673708/how-do-i-return-a-list-of-users-if-i-use-the-firebase-simple-username-password/14676121#14676121)

Comment: That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!!